# Resolving deprecated method in android

Tags: android

My app needs to support android versions from 15 to 19, so for version below 15 i am using a deprecated method and for higher version i am using the latest method provided by android.**The setup of my project is shown in screen shot below**
[image: Project setup]

Now at runtime i will check the version of android and use suitable methods accordingly. I know that if a method is deprecated it still can be used, but i had recently faced a problem with [**BitmapDrawable(bitmap)**] constructor, where in i had used this and was working fine until jelly bean but created huge problem when using it with kikkat. So i dont want to repeat the same. Now the compiler is throwing an error stating **"Call requires API level 16(current min is 15)"**. Where i have gone wrong please help.

**Screen shot of my workspace and code**
[image: Code and error]

i think the 2nd pic cannot be seen correctly, i am provided the code itself

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnColor);
    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));

    btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                ((Button) v).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#87CEFA"));
                break;

            }


            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {

                Drawable orginal = ((Button) v).getBackground();
                int currentApi = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT; 
                if(currentApi >= 16)
                    ((Button) v).setBackground(orginal);
                else
                    ((Button) v).setBackgroundDrawable(orginal);

                break;

            }


            }



            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: so you are using something that is not supported by your minimum api version.Whats the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

`@TargetApi(16)
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")`

over the `onTouch` method

Comment: Ya its working, i didn't notice that. Is this the only option??. Or any idea other than suppressing it.Thank u.

Comment: Well its the intended behavior. Eclipse sees that you are trying to use a method that might not be available and produces an error. By adding the annotations you inform eclipse that this is intended so it stops complaining :p